# Git fetch: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: git

I am using Git-Bash 1.9.5 on Windows.
The repo I am trying to `fetch` from has a URI for the format 'https://user.name@git.corpname.corpdivision/repo1/' . I have got the cert from 
'https://git.corpname.corpdivision' and put it into `curl-ca-bundle.crt` [as advised](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/phkelley/2014/01/20/adding-a-corporate-or-self-signed-certificate-authority-to-git-exes-store). I have updated my config using `git config http.sslCAInfo C:/Users/user.name/curl-ca-bundle.crt` and it now holds:

```
[http]
    sslCAInfo = C:/Users/user.name/curl-ca-bundle.crt
```

So I think everything is where it should be. Yet when I run `git fetch origin` I get

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://user.name@git.corpname.corpdivision/repo1/': SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
```

Am I missing something obvious?
Thanks